# How to pass a value from NSMutableArray to a PFUser object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a mutable array, called `mainArray`. It contains a username that is the search result of a user search. I'm displaying every search result in a custom table view cell, that also have a `UIButton` called `addButton`. I would like to add the user to the friends list of the current user, when the current user taps the `addButton`.

The problem is that i can not assign the value from "mainArray" to the "newUser". I've tried some solutions, but the result was always an error or freeze, therefore it would be amazing, if somebody could help me to solve this problem.

My last try wast this line: (it makes this warning: Incompatible pointer types sending `NSIndexPath *` to parameter of type `NSString`)

```
[newUser addUniqueObjectsFromArray:mainArray forKey:indexPath];
```

`.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"User", nil];
        self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    }

    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [mainArray count];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        DevTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];

        cell.usernameLabel.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        return cell;
    }


    - (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {


        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];


        PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
        // The problem is here.
        [newUser addUniqueObjectsFromArray:mainArray forKey:indexPath];

        PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

        if ([self isFriend:newUser]) {

            for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
                if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:newUser.objectId]){
                    NSLog(@"some log");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        else {

            [self.friends addObject:newUser];
            [friendsRelation addObject:newUser];
        }

        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
    -(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)newUser {

        for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
            if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:newUser.objectId]){
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[newUser addUniqueObjectsFromArray:mainArray forKey:indexPath];
```

You passing `NSIndexPath`where it should be an `NSString`. You need to convert your `indexPath` into a string.

So maybe something like this if you want both the section and row to be the key:

```
NSString *newUserKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
[newUser addUniqueObjectsFromArray:mainArray forKey:newUserKey];
```

EDIT:

You don't have to pass in an array of PFObjects, here is the example from Parse docs:

```
[gameScore addUniqueObjectsFromArray:@[@"flying", @"kungfu"] forKey:@"skills"];
```

As you can see they are passing in an array of strings just as you are. I would check to see that your mainArray isn't `nil`. I've tested this and it works so you are doing something else wrong other than passing in an array of strings.

Comment: I don't know his exact use, but it seems like a consistent, retrievable key would be better than something that is always different.  It will take a lot more to retrieve information from a server that's organized this way.

Comment: Doesn't works. I think i should try to change the mutable array to a PFObject.